# Consumer with wildcard syntax

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0. I want to create a consumer with wildcard syntax that would consume messages from multiple addresses. I wrote the next consumer. But it consumes from address `news.europe.#`, but not from addresses matching the wildcard syntax (`news.europe.sport`, `news.europe.politics` etc). What am I doing wrong?

Scenario:

1. Start Artemis broker
2. Send 2 messages with the producer in `news.europe.sport`, `news.europe.politics`
3. Start the consumer

Expected behavior:

- 2 messages received by the consumer

Observed behavior

- messages remain in queues
- the address `news.europe.#` has an active consumer

```java
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

import javax.jms.*;

public class ArtemisConsumer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException, InterruptedException {

        String brokerURL = "tcp://localhost:61716";
        String queueName = "news.europe.#";
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerURL);
        connectionFactory.setUser("user");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("pass");
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        Session session = connection.createSession(true, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
        Destination destination = session.createQueue(queueName);
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
        consumer.setMessageListener(new ConsumerMessageListener("Consumer"));
        Thread.sleep(60000);
        session.commit();
        session.close();
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

broker.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq">
    <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core">

        <name>QMA</name>

        <max-disk-usage>100</max-disk-usage>

        <configuration-file-refresh-period>9223372036854775807</configuration-file-refresh-period>

        <bindings-directory>${ARTEMISMQ_DATA}/bindings</bindings-directory>

        <journal-directory>${ARTEMISMQ_DATA}/journal</journal-directory>

        <large-messages-directory>${ARTEMISMQ_DATA}/largemessages</large-messages-directory>

        <paging-directory>.${ARTEMISMQ_DATA}/paging</paging-directory>

        <cluster-user>user</cluster-user>

        <cluster-password>password</cluster-password>


        <!-- Acceptors -->
        <acceptors>
            <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://0.0.0.0:61716</acceptor>
            <acceptor name="in-vm">vm://0</acceptor>
        </acceptors>
        
        <security-settings>
            <security-setting match="#">
                <permission roles="user-group" type="createNonDurableQueue"/>
                <permission roles="user-group" type="deleteNonDurableQueue"/>
                <permission roles="user-group" type="createDurableQueue"/>
                <permission roles="user-group" type="deleteDurableQueue"/>
                <permission roles="user-group" type="createAddress"/>
                <permission roles="user-group" type="deleteAddress"/>
                <permission roles="user-group" type="consume"/>
                <permission roles="user-group" type="browse"/>
                <permission roles="user-group" type="send"/>
                <permission roles="user-group" type="manage"/>
            </security-setting>
        </security-settings>
    </core>
</configuration>
```

producer

```java
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

import javax.jms.*;

public class ArtemisProducer {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        String brokerURL = "tcp://localhost:61716";
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerURL);
        connFactory.setUser("user");
        connFactory.setPassword("password");
        final Connection conn = connFactory.createConnection();
        conn.start();
        final Session sess = conn.createSession(true, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
        final Destination dest = sess.createQueue("news.europe.politics");
        final MessageProducer prod = sess.createProducer(dest);
        final Message msg = sess.createTextMessage("Sample message");
        
        prod.send(msg);
        sess.commit();
        conn.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: I added additional data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the expected behavior. This is because the feature you're using is a [wildcard **address**](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/wildcard-routing.html). In short, any messages sent to a matching address will also be routed to the wildcard address (and any queues bound to that address according to their semantics (i.e. anycast or multicast)).

In your case the wildcard address hasn't yet been created when you send your messages so there is no way for those messages to be routed to it.

FWIW, you can see this feature in action in the `topic-hierarchies` examples which ships with the broker in the `examples/features/standard` directory.

Comment: It turns out there is no way like in the classic activemq how to consume messages if they are already in several queues (for example `news.europe.sport`, `news.europe.politics`) by creating a consumer with wildcard syntax (`news.europe.sport, news.europe.>`)?

Comment: That's correct. FWIW, there was some discussion about this on [ARTEMIS-2375](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2375) awhile back.